# Using Highcharts styled mode svg patterns not exporting

Tags: highcharts

I wonder if anyone has any suggestions with this problem:

I am using styled mode for Highcharts and defining custom SVG patterns for the chart fills, however when I export the chart as an image it doesn't render the patterns and seems to default to black and white.

Defining the pattern like this:

```
// Define the patterns
Highcharts.setOptions({
defs: {
    hatchLeft: {
        tagName: 'pattern',
        id: 'hatch-left',
        etc.
```

You can see this problem in Highcharts' own example JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/pattern/ - try exporting the chart.

Anyone got any ideas? I think I could work around it by including the patternfill module and defining the patterns that way as well as in the CSS, but this feels like redundant code...

Thanks,
Rach

Answer (score 0):

To use the pattern properly you should also import the `pattern-fills` module.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e9cqgpfk/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using 'styled-mode' for the patterns as I mentioned (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns), so would prefer not to have to include a module (and all the related code) that is unnecessary for displaying it on the page.